# Validation problem for ensuring that entered value contains alphabet only

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How can i make sure at conversion and validation phase during the JSF lifecycle that entered value in `<h:inputText>` contains alphabets only?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`<f:validateRegex>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/validateRegex.html) for this.

```
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.input}" validatorMessage="Please enter alphabets only">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" />
</h:inputText>
```

It accepts the same regex syntax as the `Pattern` class. [Check its documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). You can also use `\p{Alpha}` instead.

```
    <f:validateRegex pattern="\\p{Alpha}*" />
```

Or if you're using bean validation (as confirmed by your question history), then you can also use [`@Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) for this.

```
@Pattern(regexp="\\p{Alpha}*", message="Please enter alphabets only")
private String input;
```